# clear the textbox alphabet value after I select the search results

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, rxjs

- I have a search engine code in angular2.
- when I select the search results I need to display the values in the text box with cross button next to it.
- right now I am getting the results.
- but when I type alphabet h in the text box, I see some results but when I select hover, the h alphabet not dissapperaing.
- to make it disappear I made the text box value as empty but still not working.
- providing my code and stack blitz below
- can you please help me.
- so that in future I can implement myself.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-fdwnew?file=app/app.component.ts

```or-tag-here
add(item){
        console.log("item--->", item);

    this.tags.push(item);

    this.value=''
  }

  delete(item) {  
    console.log(item);
    this.tags = this.tags.filter(x => x !== item)  
    //this.tags.push(item);    
  }
```

Comment: What you wanted to disappaer

Comment: @Ron when we edit tags in stackoverflow we need same functionality....like when i type h and select hover then h should disappear in the text box...but tags should be present with cross symbol

Comment: You can check the my answer link is provided with Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can change the HTML with ngModel which is two way binding in Angular and I feel you better maintain the independent boxes for the Input entry and list of tags

```
<div contenteditable="true"
     class="border"
     #textbox

     style="border: 2px solid black; min-height:50px; width:300px;" 
     id="txtDiv"
     (keypress)="updateKeyUp($event)" 
     >
     <!---searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)-->
     <div>
        <span           
          class="box-tag"
         *ngFor="let tag of tags">                    
          {{tag.name}}          
          <b class="close" (click)="delete(tag)">x</b>
        </span>
     </div>
 </div>
 <input [(ngModel)]="nameModel" (keypress)="updateKeyUp($event)" placeholder="Enter Tag Name">{{this.nameModel}}
<ul *ngIf="results">
  <li *ngFor="let result of results | slice:0:9" (click)="add(result)">
    <a href="{{ result.latest }}" target="_blank">
      {{ result.name }}
    </a>     
  </li>
</ul>
```

[**Demo Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-fpctty)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but in stackoverflow edit tags they have only one text box....can you refer stackoverlow edit tag functionality and gmail compose email functionality

Comment: Then you need to use this one [NgPrime Chips](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chips)